# Remote Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to understand the work client-server bluetooth. Where android is client. PC is server.

I found [code](https://github.com/luugiathuy/Remote-Bluetooth-Android). This worked an samsung galaxy 10.1 (android 3.2), but does not work an samsung galaxy s(android 2.3.3) ans htc wildfire s(android 2.2).

```
MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

---

```
    04-25 18:32:37.023: D/BluetoothCommandService(13665): setState() 1 -> 2
04-25 18:32:37.033: I/BluetoothCommandService(13665): BEGIN mConnectThread
04-25 18:32:37.063: E/BluetoothService.cpp(102): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
04-25 18:32:37.103: E/BluetoothCommandService(13665): Unable to start Service Discovery
04-25 18:32:37.103: E/BluetoothCommandService(13665): java.io.IOException: Unable to start Service Discovery
04-25 18:32:37.103: E/BluetoothCommandService(13665):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:367)
04-25 18:32:37.103: E/BluetoothCommandService(13665):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:201)
04-25 18:32:37.103: E/BluetoothCommandService(13665):   at com.luugiathuy.apps.remotebluetooth.BluetoothCommandService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothCommandService.java:258)
04-25 18:32:37.103: D/BluetoothCommandService(13665): setState() 2 -> 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your device fails for service discovery (i think so) .

1. I have read about BT issues with numerous Samsung devices and HTC devices but those where specifically for L2CAP/HID profile.
   Soln: you could use SPP or RFCOMM if you are using L2CAP
2. If you are using one of the above mentioned in solution then try using with standard UUID

SPP     00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

RFCOMM      00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

**Edit**

Alternatively you may try using reflection to get your socket connection something like the below method

```
private static BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(
        int type, int fd, boolean auth, boolean encrypt, String address, int port){
    try {
        Constructor<BluetoothSocket> constructor = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
                int.class, int.class,boolean.class,boolean.class,String.class, int.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        BluetoothSocket clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) 
            constructor.newInstance(type,fd,auth,encrypt,address,port);
        return clientSocket;
    }catch (Exception e) { return null; }
}
```

Comment: do you any new errors or same issue..and does it works with all 2.3 devices you have

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
static int sdk = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);

private static final UUID MY_UUID = 
   UUID.fromString((sdk<=8||sdk>=11)?"04c6093b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb":"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

It has worked for me :)

Tested on 2.1 - 3.3 and 4.0.4 android versions.

Comment: I think It's because newer smartphones don't use the same Bluetooth protocol than older ones and so their UUID has changed too.